# Can't transfer HDR metadata when using IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForComposition method

Tags: c++, directx-11, directx-12, hdr

According to [this MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/high-dynamic-range#setting-up-your-directx-swap-chain) metadata should be forwarded on any creation IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainFor... method. But I managed to do it only for Hwnd method.

```
D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE::D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    nullptr,
    D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT,
    nullptr, 0,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &direct3dDevice,
    nullptr,
    nullptr);

direct3dDevice.As(&dxgiDevice);

CreateDXGIFactory2(
    DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG,
    __uuidof(dxFactory),
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(dxFactory.GetAddressOf()));

DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 description = {};
description.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
description.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
description.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
description.BufferCount = 2;
description.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
description.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING;
RECT rect = {};
GetClientRect(window, &rect);
description.Width = rect.right - rect.left;
description.Height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

dxFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(dxgiDevice.Get(),
    window,
    &description,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    swapChain.GetAddressOf());

ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain4> m_swapChain;
swapChain.As(&m_swapChain);
```

When I create swap chain like ForComposition:

```
dxFactory->CreateSwapChainForComposition(dxgiDevice.Get(),
    &description,
    nullptr,
    swapChain.GetAddressOf());
```

the [IDXGISwapChain4::SetHDRMetaData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_5/nf-dxgi1_5-idxgiswapchain4-sethdrmetadata) method is executed without errors, but the metadata is not forwarded. This is also true for DirectX 12 API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are specific issues here with "Composition" swapchains, but HDR rendering requires `DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM` or `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT`  per the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/high-dynamic-range).

Your application must also handle the fact that it's a user-setting, so it may or may not be active. It also may or may not be active on the current monitor for your window. This is detected via `IDXGIOutput6` and the `DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC1.ColorSpace`.

See the **SimpleHDR** sample for [Win32 desktop](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/PCSamples/Graphics/SimpleHDR_PC12) and [UWP](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/UWPSamples/Graphics/SimpleHDR_UWP12).

Comment: Thanks for replying to me!   But I haven't found any use of the `IDXGISwapChain4::SetHDRMetaData` method in your sample. And your sample uses the CreateSwapChainFor**Hwnd** method, which I have no problem with. It works great. I took this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12HDR) as a basis, which uses the SetHDRMetaData method, but, unfortunately, it also uses the **Hwnd** method. My attempt to replace **Hwnd** with CreateSwapChainFor**Composition** makes it impossible to broadcast the HDR MetaData I need.

Comment: Hi Chuck!
I was able to pass metadata when using the IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForComposition method. The problem was in fullscreen mode. But now I am faced with a new problem. For my project, I have to use description.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED mode.
But as soon as I set it, the metadata stops streaming.
Is this an undocumented limitation or do I need to look elsewhere for the problem?